# Remove all margin from align

Tags: align, margins

Because I want to include an align environment into an itemize environment, I need to get rid of the bottom, left and top margin.

I found, that I can remove the top and bottom margin with this:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myalign*}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-\baselineskip}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{\abovedisplayskip}%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}%
{\endalign}
\makeatother
```

But this still leaves the left margin.
I tried replacing \start@align and \endalign with flalign but that caused errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the normal left margin for text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% compatibility test
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myalign*}{\ifvmode\else\hfil\null\linebreak\fi
  \hspace*{-\leftmargin}\minipage\textwidth
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{\abovedisplayskip}%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne}%
{\endalign\endminipage\linebreak}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item blah blah blah \begin{myalign*}
x & = A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P\\
y & = x-A
\end{myalign*} blah blah blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

The leftmargin comes from the itemize environment. So you have to customize this to eliminate its leftmargin:

First, in your preamble, use

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

The change your `itemize` to

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt]
```