# Remove top and bottom margins from Align to use in List

Tags: align, margins

I have achieved the block I need in my list (4th item) but I need it to align with the item label.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section*{Valence Bond Theory (VBT)}
    \textbf{Valence Bond Theory}: States that the overlapping of incompletely filled atomic orbitals leads to the formation of a chemical bond.\\

    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.6cm,itemsep=0pt,label={\arabic*}.]
        \item Covalent bond is formed by overlapping of atomic orbital, atoms should be very close.
        \item Only half-filled orbitals with electrons of opposite spin overlap.
        \item Overlapping must be $<$50\%
        \item \begin{fleqn}
            \begin{align*}
                \text{Extent of Overlapping} &\propto \text{Strength of Bond}\\
                &\propto \text{Bond Energy}\\
                &\propto \dfrac{1}{\text{Bond Length}}
            \end{align*}
        \end{fleqn}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340265/245709) yields another incorrect result.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you replace the nested `fleqn`/`align*` environments with a single `aligned[t]` environment. I further suggest that you replace `itemsep=0pt` with `noitemsep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\section*{Valence Bond Theory (VBT)}
\paragraph{Valence Bond Theory} States that the overlapping of 
incompletely filled atomic orbitals leads to the formation of 
a chemical bond.
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.6cm,noitemsep]
   \item Covalent bond is formed by overlapping of atomic 
         orbital, atoms should be very close.
   \item Only half-filled orbitals with electrons of 
         opposite spin overlap.
   \item Overlapping must be $<$\,50\%.
   \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
           \text{Extent of Overlapping} &\propto \text{Strength of Bond}\\
               &\propto \text{Bond Energy}\\
               &\propto \dfrac{1}{\text{Bond Length}}
          \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow, aligned is a total game changer, thanks a tonne!

Answer (score 4):

Here are two alternatives:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\section*{Valence Bond Theory (VBT)}
    \textbf{Valence Bond Theory}: States that the overlapping of incompletely filled atomic orbitals leads to the formation of a chemical bond.

    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.6cm,itemsep=0pt,label={\arabic*}.]
        \item Covalent bond is formed by overlapping of atomic orbital, atoms should be very close.
        \item Only half-filled orbitals with electrons of opposite spin overlap.
        \item Overlapping must be $<$50\%
        \item \abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
        \begin{fleqn}
            \begin{align*}
                \text{Extent of Overlapping} &\propto \text{Strength of Bond}\\
                &\propto \text{Bond Energy}\\
                &\propto \dfrac{1}{\text{Bond Length}}
            \end{align*}
        \end{fleqn}
        \item \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\;$\propto$\;}l}
                Extent of Overlapping & Strength of Bond\\
                & Bond Energy\\
                &  $\dfrac{1}{\text{Bond Length}}$
            \end{tabular}
        \item another item
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```